# How do I set up a DbContext to log errors to ILogger?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext, ilogger

I have an ASP.NET Core application, and in my `Startup.cs` file, in the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` function, I'm trying to write something like this:

```cs
//...

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //...

            services.AddDbContext<ModelDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Model"),
                    sqlServerOptionsAction => sqlServerOptionsAction.EnableRetryOnFailure());
                options.LogTo(
                    filter: (eventId, _) => eventId.Id == CoreEventId.ExecutionStrategyRetrying,
                    logger: (eventData) =>
                    {
                        var retryEventData = (ExecutionStrategyEventData)eventData;
                        var exceptions = retryEventData.ExceptionsEncountered;
                        var exception = exceptions[exceptions.Count - 1];
                        logger.LogWarning(exception,
                            "Database error occurred. Retry #{ExceptionsCount} with delay {RetryEventDataDelay} due to error: {ExceptionMessage}",
                            exceptions.Count, retryEventData.Delay, exception.Message);
                    });
            }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            //...
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to make this line above work:

```cs
logger.LogWarning(exception,
    "Database error occurred. Retry #{ExceptionsCount} with delay {RetryEventDataDelay} due to error: {ExceptionMessage}",
    exceptions.Count, retryEventData.Delay, exception.Message);
```

The problem is that I don't have a reference to an instance of `ILogger`, so I don't know how to call the [LogWarning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.logwarning?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) function in that context.

So my question is:

- What should I do to configure the `DbContext` with a reference to an `ILogger` instance?

  - Can I somehow use `IServiceCollection services` to construct an instance of `ILogger`? It feels a bit wrong to do that inside the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` function. Or is there another better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the other overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.1#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions-adddbcontext-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-action((system-iserviceprovider-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextoptionsbuilder))-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime)) of AddDbContext, which provides the application's IServiceProvider which you can get logger from it, but somehow this overload is documented as less preferred.

The other way is just inject ILogger into your DbContext via the constructor, and configure your logging in DbContext.OnConfiguring to log into the injected logger.

Comment: Thank you very much, that overload does exactly what I need!

No idea though why it says "*By default, we recommend using `AddDbContext<TContextService,TContextImplementation>(IServiceCollection, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)` which allows Entity Framework to create and maintain its own IServiceProvider for internal Entity Framework services.*" But it works great, so I'm happy. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is that I don't have a reference to an instance of `ILogger`" Let me start by this. You can use `ILogger<TCategoryName>` [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-logs), used to enable activation of a named ILogger using dependency injection.

Change your constructor to this.

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);
        builder.AddConsole();
        builder.AddEventSourceLogger();
    });
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
}
```

And now you can use it anywhere in the `Startup`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    _logger.LogWarning("something");
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I prefer the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832476/595990, because in that way it will use the same logger configuration as the rest of the codebase. By calling `LoggerFactory.Create(...)`, as you suggest, I would have to configure it in the same way as my other logger instances, which is not so easy in my case because I'm using a NuGet package that configures the logger and it's not so transaparent to me what it does.